Finding rational numbers between a pair
I was trying to find out rational numbers between a pair of p/q number.
On youtube a tutor told to "add 1 to the number of rational number we want to find out" say we want 5 so 5+1=6. so now we will add p6/q6 and similar to the other p6/q6, so from here whatever answer we get we just will write the in between p/q numbers. Can someone explain me why we are adding 1 .
The question is:  find 5 rational numbers between 3/5 and 4/5

What is "the number of rational number we want to find out"? If the pair is different, there should be infinite rational numbers between the pair.

It's difficult to explain what the tutor is doing without knowing what the tutor did. Can you provide a link to the video?

What does "$p/q$ number" mean, if not also rational?

You can generally form the mean value between two rational numbers and get another one exactly in the middle between them.

Guys the question is like find 5 rational numbers between 3/5 and 4/5

I’m voting to close this question because it's trivial as stated.

$\frac{3}{5}=\frac{24}{40}<?<\frac{32}{40}=\frac{4}{5}$

Hint: $3/5=18/30$ and $4/5=24/30$.

Then one approach is by linear interpolation and calculate $\left{\frac16x+\frac56y, \frac26x+\frac46y, \ldots, \frac56x+\frac16y\right}$, where $x=\frac35$ and $y=\frac45$. The "adding 1" may be because the $5$ new numbers partition the interval $\left[\frac35, \frac45\right]$ into $6$ intervals.

Thanks everyone for your time it was really helpful.


Can someone explain me why we are adding 1

It's so you don't make a fencepost error. Just work out a simple example: If you want to fill in the distance between two end-posts with a fence having 3 interior fence posts you are going to have 4 sections between posts.
(Tip of the hat to @BowieTang, whose comment clarified the question greatly.)

If $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $p<q$, then $$r_1:=\frac{p+q}{2} \in \mathbb{Q} \quad \text{and}\quad p<r_1 <q$$ Now you can proceed recursively and calculate the mean value between $r_1$ and $p$ and so on until you have numbers $r_1, \dots, r_5$ that are really greater than $p$ and really less than $q$. You can now practice this procedure using your example $\frac35$ and $\frac45$ right away.

Thank you so much for your time and effort @Noctis its clear to me now.

If [math]\frac{p}{q}[/math] and [math]\frac{r}{s}[/math] are two distinct rational numbers, then the midpoint, [math]\frac{\frac{p}{q}+ \frac{r}{s}}{2}= \frac{ps+ sq}{2qs}[/math] is a rational number between them.
We can then, find any number of rational numbers between them.

LaTeX should be put between dollar signs ($), not [math] mark-up.
